# show that a function is constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> Let $h,g\in \mathbb{R}^{R}$ s.t $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have  $(h(x)-h(y))(g(x)-g(y))=0$
>
> show that $h$=constant or $g$=constant

we have to show that

for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$h(x)=x \text{ or } g(x)=x $$
or
for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$
$$h(x)=h(y) \text{ or } g(x)=g(y) $$
let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ then we have
$(h(x)-h(y))(g(x)-g(y))=0\quad \implies $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $h$ is not constant, i.e. there are $x$ and $y$ with $h(x) \neq h(y)$. Then $g(x)=g(y)$. For any $z \neq x,y$ we either have $h(x) \neq h(z)$ or $h(y) \neq h(z)$. The first of these implies $g(z)=g(x)$, the second implies $g(z)=g(y)$. In both cases, we find $g(z)=g(x)=g(y)$. Since this holds for all $z$, $g$ must be a constant if $h$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

Verbally put since the product is zero, factors h difference or  g difference should be zero. With argument change neither h nor g changes. So at least one of them is a constant.